# Graph analysis and optimisation. Transform a UCG in a UAG while maximising total edge weights

Tags: python, optimization, graph, igraph, mathematical-optimization

I want to transform a UCG (undirected cyclic graph) into a UAG (Undirected acyclic graph)

To do so I'm looking for an algorithm that can help me prune the edges.

Let's take as example the following graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import igraph as ig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0, 1, 100],
        [0, 2, 110],
        [2, 3, 70],
        [3, 4, 100],
        [5, 3, 90],
        [1, 6, 85],
        [6, 7, 90],
        [7, 8, 100],
        [5, 6, 10],
        [4, 5, 60],
    ],
    columns=["nodeA", "nodeB", "weigth"],
)


g = ig.Graph.DataFrame(df,directed=False)

ig.plot(
    g,
    target=ax,
    edge_label=g.es["weigth"],
    edge_color=["green"]*8+["red"]*2,)
fig.show()
```

[image]

The goal is to make the graph **acyclic** by dropping edges while respecting the following conditions:

- All the nodes in the graph must remain connected
- Given two random nodes, after pruning there is a unique path connecting them
- As a loss function, we should try to maximize the sum of the weights of the edges. In the case of multiple solutions with the same total graph weight, the one with fewer edges wins.

In this example, we will drop the edges with weights 10 and 60 (The ones in red!) and we will obtain the following structure:

[image]

What kind of algorithm/ strategy could I use to prune the edges?

Comment: Your choices in altering this graph seem completely arbitrary (many other selections could be made for edges to cut or where to put a "central" node) so it isn't clear what kind of algorithm would be suitable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've tried to simplify and clarify the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very complicated description of the well-known *maximum spanning tree* problem. igraph, as well as most other graph libraries, have a function to find minimum-weight spanning trees. To get the maximum spanning tree, just negate the edge weights, then use the minimum spanning tree function.

---

> In the case of multiple solutions with the same total graph weight, the one with fewer edges wins.

All trees on `n` vertices have precisely `n-1` edges. All solutions will have the same number of edges.